# What is the difference between id & class

Tags: html, css

I know for id we have to use '#' symbol & for class '.' symbol.
But i dont know what class does & id does i use both for styling css.
Can any one help me when i want to use id & when class.is there is any major difference.

Comment: buddy, welcome to stackoverflow, but this is not the right question to ask here google and read this https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/

Comment: CSS Tricks has a nice article about this https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/

Answer (score 1):

**ID's are unique**

- Each element can have only one ID
- Each page can have only one element with that ID

**Classes are NOT unique**

- You can use the same class on multiple elements.
- You can use multiple classes on the same element.

[Source](https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/)

Answer (score 0):

The id is an identifiant which is supposed to be unique amongst its siblings.

The class is not related to uniqueness.